# How can I get random obstacles distance?

Tags: xcode

I´m new to programming but I managed to create a game where I jump over obstacles in Xcode. The problem is that the obstacles have the same distance between each other. Can anyone help me with coding my game so that the obstacles have a random distance between each other every time?

Coding for my obstacles:

```
SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[self getRandomColor] size:CGSizeMake(40, 50)];
obstacle.name = @"obstacle";
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(self.currentObstacleX, ground.position.y + ground.frame.size.height/2 + obstacle.frame.size.height/2);
obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:obstacle.size];
obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = obstacleCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
[self.world addChild:obstacle];

self.currentObstacleX += 250;
```

Comment: Try looking up a function to get a random integer and adding it to the 250 you increment currentObstacleX by...

Comment: Thank you. I´ll see what I can do!